# Bii find Warn message with Apache Xerces include

Tags: c++, xerces, biicode

When I run bii find,
I got the warn 
WARN: Can't find block candidate for: xercesc/xercesc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run "bii find", biicode parses your includes and searches for them in biicode servers. The code should already exist there. So, if you receive that message you have two explanations:

- User "xercesc" doesn't exist
- Block named "xercesc" from "xercesc" user doesn't exist

The correct form to find a dependency in biicode servers is:

```
#include "user/block/file_name"
```

For example, if you have a main.cpp file:

```
#include "fenix/log4z/log4z.h"

int main(){
 //your code to use log4z.h header        file
}
```

Then, this include means that you want to use from user "fenix", the "log4z" block and "log4z.h" header file and its dependencies (implicits and explicits).

Go to [fenix/log4z block page](https://www.biicode.com/fenix/log4z)

You can also search and explore existing code at https://www.biicode.com/explore

Comment: So you say someone should put the Apache xerces library to biicode?